# Autofilter Field using the header Name

Tags: excel, vba

i tried to use the Autofilter function  but using field with the header name "ID" instead the number of column. i tried my best and i got this error message "Advanced filter fails at iterations, run-time error 1004"

I am stuck for two days with it . thnk's for your help

code :

```
Sub AdataPreparation()
Dim WorkBk As Workbook, WorkSh As Worksheet, WrkTab As range, FilterRow As Variant
Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Documents\DataApplied.xlsm")
Set WorkSh = Sheets("sheet2") 
WorkSh.Activate 
Set WrkTab = range("A1").CurrentRegion 
WrkTab = ActiveRange
FilterRow = Application.Match("ID", WrkTab, 0)
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="="
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue probably lies in not having anything selected for your `.Autofilter` to filter. Try replacing `Selection` with a range, or the `.UsedRange`.

You also don't need `WrkTab`, I don't see it having any purpose - here I use `.Find` instead:

```
Sub AdataPreparation()
Dim WorkBk As Workbook, WorkSh As Worksheet, FilterRow As Variant

Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Documents\DataApplied.xlsm")
Set WorkSh = Sheets("sheet2")

WorkSh.Activate

FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="ID", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

WorkSh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="="
End Sub
```

I should add that it would be best for you to explicitly refer to your range instead of using `UsedRange`

Comment: .I will use this macro for several data. the purpose is to clean all data where there is blank. so i will keep usedrange. i Guess this's the best way

Comment: @phil_t If you have a new question, please use the [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and start there - but looking at your comment, what is `Sht` set to? Where do you get `LastRow` and `LastCol`? Too much is missing from that snippet to tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    r.AutoFilter
    kolumn = r.Find(what:="ID", after:=r(1)).Column
    r.AutoFilter Field:=kolumn, Criteria1:="="
End Sub
```