# Autofilter using in Field a variable instead of a number

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a new macro where I use autofilters. My program needs to read all columns and detect those where is written "Inspecc. tornillo" or ""caracterización exfoliación". I mean, the macro has to work with different excels where you don't know the order of the columns, you just know that one of them will have the name "caracterización exfoliación" and so on. So I tried to use Autofilter in this way:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nFilas, nColumnas)).AutoFilter   
**Field:=tornillo**, Criteria1:="=Inspeccionar", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=No"
```

Instead of:

```
> ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nFilas, nColumnas)).AutoFilter   
> **Field:=7**, Criteria1:="=Inspeccionar", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=No"
```

I declared the variable tornillo as variant, but it doesn't work. How could I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to find either if its "Inspecc. tornillo" or "caracterización exfoliación", are these always on the sheet? Will always be one but not the other?

Comment: Please review this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802066/autofilter-field-using-the-header-name)

Answer (score 1):

Say we have:

[image]

and we do not know which column is the *Treasure* column.  We want to find the *Treasure* column and filter it for *gold*:

```
Sub TreasureHunt()
    Dim N As Long

    N = Range("1:1").Find(what:="Treasure", after:=Range("A1")).Column
    ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=N, Criteria1:="Gold"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it worked, thank you!!! I was working with another way but I couldn't make it work:                                                                                                      iCol = lo.ListColumns("Categoría manguito").Index
lo.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nFilas, nColumnas)).AutoFilter field:=iCol, _
   Criteria1:="=Inspeccionado - No afectado", _
   Operator:=xlOr, _
   Criteria2:="=No afectado"                                                                                         But with the method find I finally could do it, so thank you so much!